# How to build the HelloWorld RenderScript application in eclipse?

Tags: android, renderscript

How to build the HelloWorld RenderScript application in eclipse? The HelloWorld RenderScript is from sdk/samples/android-11/RenderScript. I read the relevant article in 
  [1]: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/renderscript.html， which say: ScriptC_helloworld:This class is generated by the Android build tools and is the reflected version of the helloworld.rs Renderscript. But when I import this application into eclipse and build it, I can't find the ScriptC_helloworld. Who can help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The Script_C classes are all generated by the Android SDK during the build.

Did you import the project using the New Android Project wizard? Go to file/new/android project. And then select "create project from existing sample."

And did you go through all the steps to install the Android SDK in Eclipse?

If you think the SDK is installed properly and you used the Android wizard to import the sample project then you can try doing project/clean. If it works then you should see several files appear under the `gen` directory.